# C# Rfc2898DeriveBytes result differ from PHP PBKDF2

Tags: c#, php, pbkdf2

The SSO software I am trying to consume returns a URL encoded token, from which a user generates a salt value. For example:

```
$iterations = 1000;
$token="SaIp-gpEFreOJTtrhXuboFAwoBVs0PwgRpKbcTFNAQDRmTN2csxN775kjdhPYSe0tXvctPe0tkf_E48U2Jeetg2"
$salt = base64url_decode($token);
$idAndKey="test@company.com"+"aE1k9-djZ66WbUATqdHbWyJzskMI5ABS0";
$key=hash_pbkdf2('sha1',$idAndKey,$salt,$iterations,32,true);
$enKey= base64url_encode($key);//returns NTZkMjZhOWE5YjU2NDQ2NDY5NWE4MDFlNDIwNTA4NWU=
```

But, C# return CPC4OPRZEC1CLVOKDfQK7fv7iwuETvrF0 for same parameters. Here is the C# code

```
HASH_BYTES = 24;
HASH_ITERATIONS = 1000;
var token = "SaIp-gpEFreOJTtrhXuboFAwoBVs0PwgRpKbcTFNAQDRmTN2csxN775kjdhPYSe0tXvctPe0tkf_E48U2Jeetg2";
string idAndKey="test@company.com"+"aE1k9-djZ66WbUATqdHbWyJzskMI5ABS0";
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(idAndKey, HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(token)) { IterationCount = HASH_ITERATIONS };
var key = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(pbkdf2.GetBytes(HASH_BYTES));
```

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the C# code. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster I have added the C# code, Thank you